# Reference another table for row-level values - in IF condition when doing INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Tags: mysql, on-duplicate-key

I have orderlines and purchases. 
Purchases have many orderlines.

I'm trying to use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` when orderlines is a duplicate **ONLY IF** a the joined row from the purchases table has a certain column with a certain value.

```
INSERT INTO `orderlines` 
    (col1, col2) 
    VALUES 
    ('val1', 'val2') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    col3 = IF (purchases.status_id=0, 'truevalue' , col3);
```

So this query deals with the `orderlines` table exclusively. But I want to reference `purchases.status_id` from the `purchases` table.

I don't know how to make the fields from the `purchases` table available in this query.

- Do I do a LEFT JOIN at some point?
- INSERT INTO ... SELECT doesn't seem suitable to what I'm trying to do, since it tries to insert selected columns into the table itself. I just want to reference a column value for a specific row from another table for comparison only.

Comment: How does `orders` relate to `orderlines`? What's the column column or condition that matches `status_id` to what you're trying to insert/update? Using `INSERT INTO...SELECT` can work if you only select literal values in the `SELECT` statement instead of columns, using your condition in `WHERE`.  But it seems like there's another condition needed to relate the tables.

Comment: Does your insert include a column with the foreign key to the orders table?

Comment: yeah, `orderlines` table has an `order_id column`, which corresponds to the `id` column in `orders` table

Comment: I can be like `status_id=1`, hard-coded to a certain value, or set via a PHP variable. I suppose it would be convenient to be able to use the particular status_id value and have it check to match another value in another table... but not absolutely necessary at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't reference another table directly in the expression as you showed in your hypothetical solution.

The solution from Dhruv Saxena works because it uses a subquery.

But this should be easier with an `INSERT...SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO `orderlines` 
    (order_id, col1, col2, col3) 
SELECT id, 'val1', 'val2', IF(status_id=0, 'truevalue', NULL)
FROM purchases
WHERE order_id=1
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  col3 = COALESCE(VALUES(col3), col3);
```

This assigns col3 the 'truevalue' string only if the requested row from purchases has the condition status_id=0. If not, then it leaves col3 unchanged, because the NULL in the select-list makes COALESCE() return its second argument.

I'm not sure I've got the columns right for your table relationships, but this solution should demonstrate the technique.

Comment: It would seem to me that this, vs doing an explicit sub-query would both have the same big O. Would you agree?

Comment: It's O(log2n) where n is the size of the larger table of purchases or orderlines, because of doing B-tree operations of their indexes. Searching purchases.order_id is O(log2n) and inserting into the clustered index of orderlines is O(log2n). This is the same for the subquery solutions.

Comment: one note: it turns out there is potential table ambiguity here `col3 = COALESCE(VALUES(col3), col3);` It can be made more robust to handle the purchase table also having col3 via using `col3 = COALESCE(VALUES(col3), orderlines.col3);`

Comment: What an elegant solution! Wasn't even aware that `VALUES(col3)` could be used to the same effect as, for example, `NEW.col3` in a trigger.

Comment: @DhruvSaxena, Thanks! Yes, it's nice that we don't have to repeat the same literal value in two places in the statement, or if we use bound parameters, bind the same value twice.

Answer (score 1):

There can be a solution to this, however it requires me to make an assumption that your program knows what `values` are being supplied to the `INSERT` query and, as such, they're being used as variables. This is just to make sure that the subquery required in the `UDPATE` can be controlled as needed. So, for example, `INSERT INTO orderlines (col1, col2) VALUES ('val1', 'val2') ....`. That is, in this case, both these variables / values are available in the program.

---

We start with the `orderlines` table (for the purposes of this attempt, `id` is considered as the `PRIMARY KEY` here):

```
id  |  col1      |  col2      |  col3
----------------------------------------------
1   |  1 - col1  |  1 - col2  |  1 - col3
2   |  2 - col1  |  2 - col2  |  2 - col3
3   |  3 - col1  |  3 - col2  |  3 - col3
4   |  4 - col1  |  4 - col2  |  4 - col3
```

And define `purchases` table as follows (the same `id` is the `FOREIGN KEY` here in this table):

```
id  |  status_id 
-----------------
1   |  0  
2   |  1
```

Thereby indicating that it's for `id = 1` that `col3` should be updated to `truevalue` in `orderlines` table, in case the `INSERT` operation encounters a `DUPLICATE KEY` record.

---

The query would therefore be as follows:

```
INSERT INTO orderlines (id, col1, col2)
    VALUES (1, "1 - col1 - updated", "1 - col2 - updated")
    ON DUPLICATE KEY
    UPDATE 
        col3 = IF(
                     (SELECT CASE 
                                WHEN purchases.status_id = 0 THEN "truevalue" 
                             ELSE "falsevalue" 
                      END AS title 
                      FROM purchases WHERE id = 1
                     ) = "truevalue", 
                     "truevalue", 
                     col3
                 );
```

(Please also try running the same query with `id = 2` in the `INSERT` as well as `SELECT` sections of the query).

As you'd notice, the `SELECT` query requires the **same** `id` in the `WHERE` clause as the one that appears in the `INSERT` query — the potential `DUPLICATE KEY` candidate. This query would update `col3` in `orderlines` to `truevalue` for `id = 1` (for its corresponding `status_id` being `0` in `purchases` table), but would leave `col3` untouched if the same query was run for `id = 2`. The final output would be:

```
id  |  col1      |  col2      |  col3
----------------------------------------------
1   |  1 - col1  |  1 - col2  |  truevalue      ---> updated
2   |  2 - col1  |  2 - col2  |  2 - col3       ---> unchanged
3   |  3 - col1  |  3 - col2  |  3 - col3
4   |  4 - col1  |  4 - col2  |  4 - col3
```

[**Demo link**](http://rextester.com/WBIKS97661)

---

Additionally, if this query was being used in a program, then you'll also have control over specifying the value for `status_id` field.

Comment: For `FROM purchases WHERE id = 1` is there a SQL way to refer to the id value dynamically, rather than hard coding it to 1, or using a language (e.g. PHP) variable?

Comment: Why is the CASE WHEN THEN necessary? Could it just be `(SELECT purchases.status_id FROM purchases. WHERE id=1` ) = 0

Comment: `SELECT CASE` was just thought to be as one of the ways of implementing the logic. If you'd like to make a comparison the way you indicate in the comment, then it indeed looks like it should work - nice one! :). And, sure, `id = 1` needn't be hard-coded in the query. However, since I wasn't seeing how the query was constructed in the program, an assumption was made that _your program knows what values are being supplied to the query_.

Comment: So, for instance, if this was a [PDO Prepared Statement](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php), it could be written as `INSERT .... VALUES (?, ?, ?) ... (SELECT .... id = ?)` and [`bindParam()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) can be supplied with the same variable for the first and fourth positional parameters: `bindParam(1, $id)`, `bindParam(4, $id)`.

Comment: seriously thorough. I appreciate the effort put into this. The link site is new to me too.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to perform a subquery for the duplicate key update which performs the desired join.  The assumption the following query makes is that order_id is common to both orderlines & purchases and col1 has the unique key.

```
INSERT INTO `orderlines` 
    (col1, col2) 
    VALUES 
    ('val1', 'val2') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    col3 = (select IF(p.status_id=0, 'truevalue' , o.col3)
            from orderlines o
            join purchases p on p.order_id=o.order_id  -- assuming this is the proper join expression between orderlines and purchases
            and o.col1='val1');                        -- and col1 has the unique key
```

Comment: INSERT statements are O(n) since INSERT acts on one row, correct?
Does this query make it 2*O(n)?

Comment: I don't know what you are asking but I'll try...  You are correct, the insert acts on one row.  The update acts on the same row so we can say "update col3 = ....".  The problem is that we need information from purchases which we can be retrieved through subquery.  But the subquery uses another copy of the table in memory and doesn't know which row we're working with.  Assuming col1 is the key being duplicated, we look for the match where "col1='val1'".  The subquery needs to return a single value which may not necessarily by achieved by the query above but suggests how it might be done.

Comment: I see. so since the subquery uses the one in memory it should be not as bad as making a separate insert query and a separate select query